# Is the distinction between parametric and non-parametric statistics always clear-cut?

Tags: nonparametric, parameterization, nonparametric-regression

Is the distinction between parametric and non-parametric statistics always clear-cut or do examples of a statistic exists which cannot clearly assigned to one of these categories?

Answer (score 1):

There are semiparametric methods which fall somewhere in between. A famous example is the [Cox proportional hazards model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model), which has a nonparametric and a parametric model component.